# Android how to start Activity when ACTION_SCREEN_ON and App is terminated

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I want  my app able to start an Activity whenever the app is **terminated** or **running**. but my code seems not work

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>



  public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
           Log.e("BAM","ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
           Intent i = new Intent(context, SecondMainActivity.class); 
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

should I call the *BootReceiver* in the OnCreate activity?

Comment: AFAIK, You cannot start that, but there is one option that send notification message with pending intent on which click start activity.

Comment: no, i dont want user interaction. I want whenever the screen is wake it will start activity

Comment: If you find any answer, please post answer it here. So, I also want to know if that possible how can.